# Object casting duplicated shadows on different objects

Tags: tracking, shadows, viewlayers

I'm inserting few objects in blender after doing motion tracking on a video.
There's a plane that represents the floor (set as shadow catcher) and then, as you can see in the image there's a sort of disc on which I put a sitting character. I don't understand why, but the character is casting a full shadow both on the disc and on the floor below it.
[image: Duplicated shadow]

I would expect that the shadow on the floor would only be the character's parts exceeding the disc, but they are both "full" shadows. What am I missing here? Something about view layers? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please share a simple sample file with this problem? https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you use this set condition ...

[image]

Upper Plane is with *Visibility >* **Shadow Off** ... Lower Plane with *Ray Visibility* > **Shadow Catcher On**

[image]

To fill your expectations (if I reconstruct your scene right) - your shadow catcher object should be at the same height as the disc with Ray Visibility On.